# question about eregi() and preg_match()

Tags: php, preg-match, eregi

My code was

`if(eregi($pattern,$file)){
$out['file'][]=$file;
}else`

But is doesn't work in php 5.3, it shows the alert

`Function eregi() is deprecated`

so I changed to

`if(preg_match($pattern,$file)){
$out['file'][]=$file;
}else`

But now it shows

`preg_match(): No ending delimiter '.' found`

Did I enter any wrong syntax?

Comment: The error message `Function eregi() is deprecated` is a warning. It does not mean what you think it means. The function is **still working**. It says that it **might not** work in future PHP versions. (Unlikely)

Comment: @mario I believe it's expected to be removed in PHP6, though who knows when that will be. :-)

Comment: @Wiseguy: Since the plans for the mythical PHP6 were retired, so were the musings of actual deprecation. There's no roadmap, so this is speculation. (And not an overly probable one anyway.)

Comment: @mario Thanks. It's often hard to find what is or is not official.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern needs to have some sort of [delimiter character](http://us.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) surrounding it.

```
if(preg_match('/' . $pattern . '/',$file)){
```

`/` is typical, but "any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character" could be used. Just make sure your delimiter character doesn't appear in the `$pattern` itself.

So if your pattern was `http://(.*)`, which already has `/` characters in it, you might want to choose something else like `~`:

```
if(preg_match('~' . $pattern . '~',$file)){
```

Alternatively, as [@jensgram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52162/jensgram) notes below, if you can't guarantee your pattern won't contain a certain delimiter character, you could escape those characters in the pattern with [preg_quote()](http://php.net/preg_quote), like so:

```
if(preg_match('~' . preg_quote($pattern, '~') . '~',$file)){
```

---

Oh, also, since you're using `eregi()` (case-insensitive), you'll want to add the [`i` modifier](http://us.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for case-insensitive to your pattern, outside the delimiter.

```
if(preg_match('~' . $pattern . '~i',$file)){
```

Comment: Consider [`preg_quote()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php): `preg_match('~' . preg_quote($pattern, '~') . '~i', $file)`. It may prove useful should you ever add the delimiter to the `$pattern`.

Comment: Indeed, I thought about mentioning that. I'll add it.

Comment: Of course, if you are using `preg_quote()` on the whole pattern, you could replace it all with `strpos()` :)